# How to display names next to bubbles in d3js motion chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, bubble-chart

In Mike Bostocks example http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/ there is so much data that putting the names of the countries there would make it chaotic, but for a smaller project I would like to display it.

[image]

I found this in the source:

```
var dot = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "dots")
.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(interpolateData(2004))
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .call(position)
  .sort(order);

dot.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

But somehow a title never shows up. Does anybody have an idea, how to display the name, next to the bubble?

Comment: you have to wrap the circle element and text together

Comment: sorry but the json file looks like this [{"name":"Angola","region":"Sub-Saharan Africa","income":[[1800,359.93],[1820,359.93]],"population":[[1800,1567028],[1820,1567028]],"lifeExpectancy":[[1800,26.98],[1940,26.98]]}    Can I not go with this data and make it happen in the Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, you need to group your elements together. In addition, you need to append a `text` element -- the `title` element only displays as a tooltip in SVG. The code you're looking for would look something like this.

```
var dot = svg.append("g")
             .attr("class", "dots")
             .selectAll(".dot")
             .data(interpolateData(2004))
             .enter()
             .append("g")
             .attr("class", "dot")
             .call(position)
             .sort(order);
dot.append("circle")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });

dot.append("text")
   .attr("y", 10)
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

In the call to `position`, you would need to set the `transform` attribute. You may have to adjust the coordinates of the `text` element.

Comment: I had tried this earlier and tried it again, but there is no text displayed anywhere. The title by the way shows up on mouseover, but no text is seen anywhere.

Comment: Ahh ok, you're appending the `title` to the `text`. That would work like a tooltip -- is that what you want? Could you post your complete code somewhere please, e.g. on [vida.io](http://vida.io/)?

Comment: Sorry I tried to make it work on vida.io but couldn't get it working... the full code is the example on http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/. what I want is not a tooltip (that is already implemented right now), but a text inside the bubble that gets shifted as the bubble is shifted. I got it working that the text is displayed now but its not shifting with the bubble...

Comment: var dot2 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "dots")
     .selectAll(".dot")
       .data(interpolateData(2008))
     .enter().append("text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("dy", ".3em")
   .call(positiontext)
   .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d); })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

Comment: What's your `positiontext` implementation? It's easiest to set `transform` on the `g` element.

Comment: function positiontext(dot) {
    dot .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
        .attr("font-size", "20px")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-30)");
  }    the transform moved the text, but its still fixed on one spot and doesn't get moved the same way the circle get moved around...

Comment: the circle has this function      function position(dot) {
    dot .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radiusScale(radius(d)); });
  }

Comment: Better to put everything in a `g` element -- I'll edit my answer.

Comment: t.h.a.n.k.s. for all your help Lars, but that also doesn't work...Nothing gets displayed with your edited answer...

Comment: Could you put up a complete example somewhere please?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately grouping the text and circles together will not help in this case.  The bubbles are moved by changing their position attributes (cx and cy), but  elements do not have x and y positions to move.  They can only be moved with a transform-translate.  See: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js

Your options here are:

1) rewrite the position function to calculate the position difference (change in x and change in y) between the elements current position and its new position and apply that to the .  THIS WOULD BE VERY DIFFICULT.

or 2) Write a parallel set of instructions to setup and move the tags.  Something like:

```
var tag = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tag")
.selectAll(".tag")
  .data(interpolateData(2004))
.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "tag")
  .attr("text-anchor", "left")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .call(tagposition)
  .sort(order);
```

You will need a separate tagposition function since text needs 'x' and 'y' instead of 'cx', 'cy', and 'r' attributes.  Don't forget to update the "displayYear" function to change the tag positions as well.  You will probably want to offset the text from the bubbles, but making sure the text does not overlap is a much more complicated problem: http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6688739

PS- I called them tags since 'label' already means something in that example.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the circle element and text together , it should look like

```
<country>
   <circle ></circle>
   <text></text>
</country>
```